# How to trim a json doc to single line

Tags: python, json, ansible

I'm using [json2yaml](https://www.json2yaml.com/) to convert a yaml doc to a json string. Now i want to pass the json doc as single-line argument as  `ansible_extravars` in order to override the repository settings.

For example:

Yaml:

```
container:
    name: "summary"
    version: "1.0.0"
    some_level: "3"
    another_nested:
        schema: "summary"
        items_string: "really just a string of words"
```

json doc: (this was generated by the 'json2yaml' webpage)

```
{  "container": {
    "name": "summary",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "some_level": "3",
    "another_nested": {
      "schema": "summary",
      "items_string": "really just a string of words"
    }
  }
}
```

I was using a shell command as follows:
`% cat json_text.txt | tr -d '[:space:]'`

Which is obviously also stripping white-space from the `container.another_nested.items_string`

Output:

    `{"container":{"name":"summary","version":"1.0.0","some_level":"3","another_nested":{"schema":"summary","items_string":"reallyjustastringofwords"}}}`

How can i convert a json doc to single line and preserve white-space in quoted strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to remove the line breaks with `tr -d '[\r\n]'` instead of all white space.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

filter_chars = [' ', '\t', '\n', '\r']


def is_filtered_char(c):
    return c in filter_chars


def is_filtered_eol_char(c):
    return c in ['\n', '\r']

inside_double_quoted_string = inside_single_quoted_string = False
some_chars = sys.stdin.read()
for c in some_chars:
    if c == '"':
        if not inside_double_quoted_string:
            inside_double_quoted_string = True
        else:
            inside_double_quoted_string = False
    if c == "'":
        if not inside_single_quoted_string:
            inside_single_quoted_string = True
        else:
            inside_single_quoted_string = False

    if not inside_double_quoted_string and not inside_single_quoted_string and not is_filtered_char(c):
        sys.stdout.write(c)
    elif (inside_double_quoted_string or inside_single_quoted_string) and not is_filtered_eol_char(c):
        sys.stdout.write(c)
```

```

Usgage:

`% cat blah.txt | ./remove_ws.py
{"container":{"name":"summary","version":"1.0.0","some_level":"3","another_nested":{"schema":"summary","items_string":"really just a string of words"}}}`

Comment: Just found out about '-c (compact)' option to the 'json-query (jq)' tool:

    `jq -c '.' blah.txt`